# Hibernate + Scala: Error when deleting and re-inserting children

Tags: scala, hibernate

I have the following Hibernate classes `Group` and `Items` in Scala where one `Group` contains many `Items`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
class Item extends Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="group_sk", nullable=false)
    var group: Group = _

    @Id
    var index: Int = _

    var name: String = _

    def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[Item]

    override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
        that match {
            case that: Item => that.canEqual(this) && this.hashCode == that.hashCode
            case _ => false
     }

    override def hashCode: Int = {
        val prime = 31
        var result = 1
        result = prime * result + group.sk;
        result = prime * result + index
        return result
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "group_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="group_generator", 
    sequenceName = "GroupSeq", allocationSize = 1)    
    var sk: Int = _

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    var name: String = _

    @OneToMany(cascade=Array(CascadeType.ALL))
    @JoinColumn(name="group_sk") 
    var items: java.util.List[Item] = _
}
```

Assume I have Group 1 with Items A and B. To update the Group, I let the user edit the Items, so when I save the Group, I first clear the Items array and then append the new Items (note that the user may leave some items, so those will be deleted and re-inserted):

```
val group = session.get(classOf[Group],groupCode)
session.beginTransaction
group.name = "Group 1x"
group.items.clear
for (i <- updatedItems) {
      val it = new Item 
      it.group = group
      it.index = i.index
      it.name = i.name
      group.itemss.add(it)
}
session.update(group)
session.getTransaction.commit
```

When I try to update, I get the following error:

> Execution exception[[Exception: Failure in applyReq: A different
>   object with the same identifier value was already associated with the
>   session :
>   [admin.group.manage.Item#admin.group.manage.Item@50ec]]]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify an object that already exists in hibernate session, you can't just create a new object, set the same id and expect, that it will update the original object. You need to actually retrive the original object from the session and then modify it.

Replace

```
val it = new Item
```

with

```
val it = session.get(classOf[Item], i.index)
```

Comment: The `@Id` of `Item` contains two columns, `group` and `index`, do I have to create a new class with these two fields to get/read the item?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, that you have a composite key here. I think that creating new class to represent a composite key is more elegant solution, but you can actually cope without it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375019/hibernate-compsite-key-without-new-class